# Can I plot a y = x formula on the Arduino plotter?

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to plot a simple mathmatical function on the Arduino's Serial plotter?
Just the standard format of y = x + b? I know you can plot sensory input's onto the plotter but I'm not sure how to plot a y = x + b on the Serial plotter. Right now I've got the following:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int x;
  int LineFormula = x + 10;
  x + 5;
  delay(10);
  

}
```

If this isn't possible, are there any other options for me to use? I need to use an Arduino for the input but i'd like to see a little graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually send a value through the serial interface.

```
Serial.println(LineFormula);
```

Your code only calculates `LineFormula` from `x`.

You also forgot to initialize `x` with a value!